# Class AXAccessQueue is implemented in both...and...One of the two will be used

Tags: ios, xcode10

`Xcode10` runs a blank project. I select `Simulator iPhoneXR`.  The console prints as follows

```
Class AXAccessQueue is implemented in both...and...One of the two will be used.
Class AXAccessQueueTimer is implemented in both...and...One of the two will be used.
[AXMediaCommon] Unable to look up screen scale
[AXMediaCommon] Unexpected physical screen
```

I change simulator `iPhone6`. The console prints

```
libMobileGestalt  MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.
```

How to produce this kind of phenomenon? and How to solve the problem?

I will appreciate your answer.

Comment: Same problem here, appears when I use an XCTAssert with NSPredicate matching

Comment: In my case it happened in UITest when added additional NSLayoutConstraint